# Reference request: transforming a grammar to Greibach normal form preserves the number of parse trees

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, grammars

I believe that most "natural" ways of transforming a grammar to the GNF should preserve the number
of parse trees for each string. For example, Urbanek's construction from the paper 
"On Greibach normal form construction" seems to do the job.

What I need is the statement that for every context-free grammar there exists a grammar
in GNF that every word has the same number of parse trees for both grammars (therefore
this grammars define the same language; but it should be noted that the equality of 
the number of the parse trees is stronger condition).

Unfortunately, proving this rigorously looks really tedious and probably won't 
add any conceptual value to the paper I currently participate
in writing. Moreover, this result can't possibly be original and therefore
it is much better to cite it rather than to reprove it again. However, all my
attempts to find a paper where this result is stated directly were futile.

Some requirements (all not strict, though):

1. For simplicity of quoting, I would prefer a paper where this result is stated 
   as a theorem, lemma, corollary or something "noticeable" like this, preferably 
   not as a remark in the middle of the proof (though the latter also would be okay 
   for the lack of the former).
2. Situations, where this result is not stated at all and just immediately 
   follows from some deeper theory (but the fact that it follows *is not* established in the paper)
   are less preferable, of course, but still fine, as long as the main results of the theory are
   easy to state.
3. In the same vein, if the result is proved for weighted grammars 
   (with the number of parse trees being replaced with weigt of the word), 
   it is completely fine.

While not probable, it still may happen that this result is incorrect. In this case, link to the disproof or a disproof as the answer would be nice.

**UPD** It seems that lemma 4 in this [paper](https://www7.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/um/bibdb/kiefer/14FJKW-IC.pdf) does the job. However, if 
someone finds a link that does not mention multigrammar, I would still appreciate that.